# When choosing an SCD type for a data-warehouse, what things do you have to consider?

Tags: data-warehouse

For each case what are the considerations for the fact tables ?
How do the changes in the dimension effect the fact tables and how are these  handled in the fact tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest part of the answer is about fact tables. There are no changes, regardless of the dimension type. This is because the relationship between the fact and dimension is the dimension's surrogate key.

For dimensions, you need to decide which columns can change, and whether you need to know their previous value.

If none of the columns can change, then SCD0 is usually the most appropriate. You'd use this for something like a calendar, perhaps, where the data is constant, unless we revert to medieval papism instead of an atomic clock :)

Sometimes you don't care about the previous value, only the current value is important regardless of the age of the fact. An example here MIGHT be a customer's telephone number. I say "might", because that significance depends on business rules. These are SCD1 dimensions.

If we care about previous history, we need to make a choice between SCD2 and SCD3.

SCD2 creates a new row each time the dimension data changes. The business key remains constant, but facts relating to the new time period will have the new row surrogate key. An example might be Customer Address, where the customer is always identified by the business key C12345, but fact tables point to IDs 13, 987 and 2465 representing the changes in address as that customer shifted house, town, etc.

SCD3 maintains a "previous" value in the current row. If all we needed to know was the current value of a field and its previous value, we don't need to create a new row each time that value changes. Updating an SCD3 dimension needs to shift the "current" value to the "previous" value, then write the new value to the "current" value.

Now, the terminology gets a little messy, because a dimension can actually combine all of these types in one. Consider a theoretical Bank Account dimension:

- ID (surrogate key)
- Number (business key)
- Account Name (SCD1, depending on business rules)
- Opening Balance (SCD0)
- Authorised Signatory (SCD2, we want a record of who was authorised at a point in time)
- Relationship Manager (SCD3, I want the current and prior)

The SCD type tells me what needs to be updated when any of these columns changes.

- SCD0: This value should never change, no updates required.
- SCD1: Update ALL rows for the business key.
- SCD2: Create a new row whenever this value changes
- SCD3: Update all previous and current values for the business key

Kimball further defines SCD4-6, but these are much less commonly used. I won't go into the details, this answer is getting long enough :)

Finally, there is the issue of cardinality to consider. If your fact can be related to more than one dimension row at a time, then you might need a Bridge table to handle the relationship.

In summary:

- Your fact tables contain foreign keys to dimension tables
- Dimension rows are identified by surrogate keys
- There may be many dimension rows for a given business key, depending on history requirements.